# Compare cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have some data like below in one column.

```
Value
-----
A#show  
20
20
B#show  
20
25
30
C#show  
10
10
10
10
D#show  
10
E#show
10
20
```

I want to compare the values between the cell where the last string is "show" and if there is only one then no comparison.

```
Value       Comparison 
----------------------
A#show      Same
20  
20  
B#show      different
20  
25  
30  
C#show      same
10  
10  
10  
10  
D#show      only one
10  
E#show      different
10  
20
```

I think it's can be possible using a VBA script

Comment: You are certainly correct - it is possible using VBA.  Have you tried anything and are you having problems?  If so, post your code and describe your problems.  If not, try something - SO is not a "code for me" site.

Comment: Comparing values working from the bottom up would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: i have tried to make a script but it's not working . will you please help me to right the script

Comment: Please post your not-working code and I'm sure you'll get some suggestions

Comment: i just wright the below code to compare value in 2 cell but don't getting any idea how to run a for loop to compare 2 or multiple of cells .                                                        Sub Button3_Click()
If (Range("A3").Value = Range("A4").Value) Then
    Range("B2").Value = "same"
Else
    Range("B1").Value = "Different"
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to compare between values. However, there is a way to do this without VBA.

1) In the Second Column, create a "Header" column which names which header each value belongs to. The first entry would just be A#show, but then the following would be:
=IFERROR(IF(A2*1>0,B1),B2)

2) In the third column, you can utilize countif to see if the header has more than 2 entries (indicating it has a comparison). Here is where you can apply whatever comparative metric you'd like. If it's something unformulaic, just use a pivot table with the 3 columns.

Comment: I want to compare the values between the cell where the last string is "show" and if there is only one then no comparison.

Comment: That's exactly what the 2nd and third column are doing. If the count is , then there is only 1 entry (since the title counts) and no comparison is needed. If it's more than 2 then you can execute whatever comparison code you want to run

Comment: how it will match the last keyword show and compare the value between this to cell